# Dropdown list with conditions on other dropdown list

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I make a drop-down list from several lists with a condition from another drop-down list?

Using my image above, let's say I on the first drop-down list (this one is a simple one) select "Furniture"... I would like the second drop-down list to only show the furniture. Same thing with the third drop-down list, would like only the color of my second choice to be shown there.

Did try to place on the criteria "Custom formula" in the "Data validation" one of this two formulas but does not work...

```
=FILTER(Object,Type = E2)
```

or

```
=QUERY(A:C,"SELECT B WHERE A='"&E2&"' ", 0)
```

Did read in some other topic here that it was not possible with formulas and I could not find an app script for it. How can i place conditional rules and make only appear the values i want on the drop-down menu instead all of them ? I think it has something to do with the "withCriteria(criteria, args)" however i am not understanding how to apply it.

About the list ... it will be compose maybe with 2k lines (each line 3 columns). First column will only have (maybe) 6 or 7 different values. Second about 70 or 80 and third all different. The order will be random cause new values could be added and i can be adding a new Furniture or Animal ...

This is the code i have now

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if ( range.getRow() > 1) {
    if ( range.getColumn() == 5) {
      var cell_Range = ss.getRange( range.getRow(), range.getColumn() + 1);
      var cell = cell_Range.getCell( 1, 1);
      var rangeV = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B2:B13');
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rangeV).build();
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);
    }
    else if ( range.getColumn() == 6 ) { 
      var cell_Range = ss.getRange( range.getRow(), range.getColumn() + 1);
      var cell = cell_Range.getCell( 1, 1);
      var rangeV = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C2:C13');
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rangeV).build();
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);

    }
  }
}
```

Example sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aLpYd8fC0jpwvQOPVTj_yvY7DVKeFFnPvpJSF27if6w/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use intermediate ranges that use the formulas you reference. Assign those intermediate ranges as the sources of the dropdowns. This requires a 1-way flow of picking (i.e. must go type->object->color, not color->type->object)

Comment: but that will make me to do allot of intermediate ranges ... If i have 100 drop-down menus i will have to make 100 intermediate ranges. Isn't there any other way like with app script ?

Comment: ohh ???? a good question ??? Why is this one not a good question ?

Comment: Yes, a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about Apps Script code will include the code that you have already tried. A question that just asks "is (some complex task) possible? If so, give me an example" is not a good question. For starters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587704/how-to-use-google-apps-script-range-setdatavalidation There are other questions that use Apps Script to control drop-down options, and your question shows no evidence of having reviewed or attempted anything tried in them.

Comment: The issue is that when i click on the cell, nothing happens and i should (in this case) populate the cell with the correct option

Comment: Please [Edit] to include all updates including code. Comments will be deleted.

Comment: I think I'd probably do this in a dialog with javascript and a select tag.

Comment: yehh i think i will use copper idea , it should be easier. But just to finish part of this, how can i use the two columns criteria to show on F2 cell. Atm F2 is showing all values on it but i want to filter it according to the E2 value.

Comment: @Miguel [Edit] to include  your current issue with the code, if any. Right now, Your question doesn't have a question. Will your range be always ordered like that? Like If A2:A6 is "Animal", Two "Cat"s will be  ordered consequetively? - Or will the two "Cat"s be ordered anywhere in B2:B6?

Comment: "Animal" on the first input is just an example... However if i choose Animal in the first input the idea is only to show all the Animals on the Second input (Cat, Dog, Ping and Donkey)... If second input i choose "cat" the third one should have only "White" and "Black" option to choose. The order can be different cause this is just a small example with not very accurate values as well.

Comment: @Mig I understand all that. What I'm asking is, Inside "Animal"(A2:A6) , If there are 2 cats, Is it possible that 1 cat is in B2 and other is in B4?  (instead of being **consecutively**)coz... If that order is different, there's no more a range to set. Also, How many entries are we talking here? PS:Your q still doesn't have a question.

Comment: Topic edited... and no they will not be orderer no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Use Datavalidation requireValueInList

#### Flow:

- Get All options `A1:C` as a array
- Filter A(Col1) if edited value in E(Col5) is present in it
- Retrieve  corresponding Col2(B) as options and build data validation based on it
- Offset the edited range by 1 column and set DataValidation

#### Sample Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const SETTINGS = {
    //Edited Column : Column to Check(First col in optionsDataRange is considered 1)
    5: 1,
    6: 2,
  };
  var editedRange = e.range,
    editedSheet = editedRange.getSheet(),
    val = e.value,
    col = editedRange.columnStart,
    row = editedRange.rowStart;

  /*Exit clause(s)*/
  if (
    Object.keys(SETTINGS).indexOf(col.toString()) === -1 || //If edited col is not in settings
    editedSheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1' ||
    row > 5
  )
    return;

  var optionsDataRange = editedSheet
    .getRange(1, 1, editedSheet.getLastRow(), 3)
    .getValues();

  /*Only get options where val is present in optionsDataRange*/
  var options = optionsDataRange
    .map(function(e) {
      return e[SETTINGS[col] - 1] == val ? e[SETTINGS[col]] : null;
    })
    .filter(function(e, i, a) {
      return e !== null && a.indexOf(e) === i;
    });

  var dv = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(options)
    .build();
  editedRange.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(dv);
}
```

#### References:

- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: That "var options = ..." kills me lol... Been here trying to understand it but it's way over my head. But it works indeed... many appreciate mate

Comment: @Miguel Are you clear with Array#map?  The `oDataRange` is a 2D array. `e` will be a 1D array(each row). In each row, if edited column is 5, Col1 will be checked for `val`,if present -> returns the next Col value in `oDR`(i.e., ``Col2``), else `null` is returned(which is filtered out later)

Comment: Add a reference to simple trigger restrictions.. @miguel review what comprises a JavaScript statement, including ASI (automatic semicolon insertion).

Comment: Well the issue i have with such codes is that i am not able to understand mentally what the code is doing and when i try to understand how a code works i mean that. In this particular case it's not the map  itself but all variables that have a function inside it (for some reason) i am not able to mentally understand the "cog and wheels" behind it and therefor it complicates things.

Comment: One other thing that is very rare i use (i mean i have never used it) is that kinf of if statement with the "?" and ":". I remember read it somewhere but in my mind it does not makes sense the way to do that so i have never used it. Is that what you mean by ASI   tehhowch ? going to google

Comment: @Mig https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator